# How can I find, increment and replace in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, backreference

I have strings in the form `\d+_\d+` and I want to add 1 to the second number. Since my explanation is so very clear, let me give you a few examples:

- 1234567_2 should become 1234567_3
- 1234_10 should become 1234_11

Here is my first attempt:

```
$new = preg_replace("/(\d+)_(\d+)/", "$1_".((int)$2)+1, $old);
```

This results in a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'
>   in [...] on line 201

Here is my second attempt

```
$new = preg_replace("/(\d+)_(\d+)/", "$1_".("$2"+1), $old);
```

This transforms $old = 1234567_2 into $new = 1234567_1, which is not the desired effect

My third attempt

```
$new = preg_replace("/(\d+)_(\d+)/", "$1_".((int)"$2"+1), $old);
```

This yeilds the same result.

By making these attempts, I realized I didn't understand how the new $1, $2, $3, .. variables really worked, and so I don't really know what else to try because it seems that these variables no longer exist upon exiting the preg_replace function...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$new = preg_replace("/(\d+)_(\d+)/e", '"$1_" . ("$2" + 1)', $old);
```

The `$1` etc terms are not actually variables, they are strings that `preg_replace` will interpret in the replacement text.  So there is no way to do this using straight text-based `preg_replace`.

However, the `/e` modifier on the regular expression asks `preg_replace` to interpret the substitution *as code*, where the tokens `$1` etc will actually be treated as variables.  You supply the code as a string, and `preg_replace` will `eval()` it in the proper context, using its result as the replacement.

Comment: It works! There is just one small detail which you didn't explain: Why do you have to add the single quotes (') around the second parameter?

Comment: I did sort of explain that -- as I said, the `/e` modifier causes `preg_replace` to interpret the substitution string as code that will be evaluated with `eval()`.  There really isn't any other way to specify code, at least not before PHP supported lambdas (and I don't think `preg_replace` supports them).

Comment: Please note that the /e modifier is deprecated. See MythTrazz's answer for a newer solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution for the PHP 5.3 (now when PHP supports lambdas)

```
$new = preg_replace_callback("/(\d+_)(\d+)", function($matches)
{
    return $matches[1] . (1 + $matches[2]);
}
, $new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` (step-by-step):

```
$string = "123456_2";

echo $string;

$parts = explode("_", $string);

$lastpart = (int)$parts[1];

$lastpart++;

$newstring = $parts[0] . "_" . (string)$lastpart;

echo $newstring;
```

This separates the string on the "_" character and converts the second part to an integer. After incrementing the integer, the string is recreated.